# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCount Error, how to fix this?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught ArgumentCountError: 6 arguments are required, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\web ecom\wp-content\plugins\astra-sites\inc\classes\class-astra-sites.php:2646 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\web ecom\wp-content\plugins\astra-sites\inc\classes\class-astra-sites.php(2646): sprintf('<div class="not...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\web ecom\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): Astra_Sites->admin_welcome_notices('') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\web ecom\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\web ecom\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\web ecom\wp-admin\admin-header.php(303): do_action('admin_notices') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\web ecom\wp-admin\index.php(137): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\web ecom\wp-content\plugins\astra-sites\inc\classes\class-astra-sites.php on line 2646

[Line 2646](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/astra-sites/tags/3.4.3/inc/classes/class-astra-sites.php#L2646) in class-astra-sites.php is the one that starts with `'message' => sprintf(`.

This is the entire code from the related function:

```php
public function admin_welcome_notices() {
    $first_import_status = get_option( 'astra_sites_import_complete', false );
    Astra_Notices::add_notice(
        array(
            'id'      => 'astra-sites-welcome-notice',
            'type'    => 'notice',
            'class'   => 'astra-sites-welcome',
            'show_if' => ( false === Astra_Sites_White_Label::get_instance()->is_white_labeled() && empty( $first_import_status ) ),
            /* translators: %1$s white label plugin name and %2$s deactivation link */
            'message' => sprintf(
                '<div class="notice-welcome-container"> 
                    <div class="text-section">
                        <h1 class="text-heading">' . __( 'Welcome to Starter Templates!', 'astra-sites' ) . '</h1>
                        <p>' . __( 'Create professionally designed pixel-perfect websites in minutes.', 'astra-sites' ) . '</p>
                        <a href="/wp-admin/themes.php?page=starter-templates" class="text-button">' . __( 'Get Started', 'astra-sites' ) . '</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="showcase-section">
                        <img src="' . esc_url( ASTRA_SITES_URI . 'inc/assets/images/templates-showcase.png' ) . '" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="notice-content-container">
                    <div class="content-section">
                        <div class="icon-section">
                        <img src="' . esc_url( ASTRA_SITES_URI . 'inc/assets/images/dashicons-cart.svg' ) . '" /></div>
                        <div class="link-section">
                            <h4>' . __( 'Ecommerce', 'astra-sites' ) . '</h4>
                            <p>' . __( 'Looking for a fully operational eCommerce template to launch a store or level up an existing one?', 'astra-sites' ) . '</p>
                            <a href="/wp-admin/themes.php?page=starter-templates&ci=1&s=E-Commerce">' . __( 'View Ecommerce Templates', 'astra-sites' ) . ' →</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-section">
                        <div class="icon-section">
                        <img src="' . esc_url( ASTRA_SITES_URI . 'inc/assets/images/dashicons-building.svg' ) . '" /></div>
                        <div class="link-section">
                            <h4>' . __( 'Local Business', 'astra-sites' ) . '</h4>
                            <p>' . __( 'Fully customizable local business templates that can deliver a fully functioning website in minutes', 'astra-sites' ) . '</p>
                            <a href="/wp-admin/themes.php?page=starter-templates&ci=1&s=Business">' . __( 'View Local Business Templates', 'astra-sites' ) . ' →</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-section">
                        <div class="icon-section">
                        <img src="' . esc_url( ASTRA_SITES_URI . 'inc/assets/images/dashicons-megaphone.svg' ) . '" /></div>
                        <div class="link-section">
                            <h4>' . __( 'Agency', 'astra-sites' ) . '</h4>
                            <p>' . __( 'Do more in less time with Starter Templates. Pro-quality designs that can be fully customized to suit your clients.', 'astra-sites' ) . '</p>
                            <a href="/wp-admin/themes.php?page=starter-templates&ci=1&s=Agency">' . __( 'View Agency Templates', 'astra-sites' ) . ' →</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-section">
                        <div class="icon-section">
                        <img src="' . esc_url( ASTRA_SITES_URI . 'inc/assets/images/dashicons-welcome-write-blog.svg' ) . '" /></div>
                        <div class="link-section">
                            <h4>' . __( 'Blog', 'astra-sites' ) . '</h4>
                            <p>' . __( 'Customizable blog templates covering every niche. Page builder compatible, easy to use and fast!', 'astra-sites' ) . '</p>
                            <a href="/wp-admin/themes.php?page=starter-templates&ci=1&s=Blog">' . __( 'View Blog Templates', 'astra-sites' ) . ' →</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>'
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: This plugin has a [support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/astra-sites/) and it seems to be actively monitored by its developers. If you haven't done so yet, try posting on their support forum so they can help you fix this issue.